# ViewModelLocator in prism mvvm

Tags: mvvm, uwp, prism

Here is my Scenario,I need to create a simple uwp app and I have got a single viewmodel and multiple views..I am using prism mvvm/unity .

MainPage.xaml

```
  <prism:SessionStateAwarePage
x:Class="MvvmSample.Views.MainPage"
xmlns:prism="using:Prism.Windows.Mvvm"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:MvvmSample"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="29.333" />
    <Button Content="Navigate" Command="{Binding del}"/>
</Grid>
```

Viewmodels.MainpageViewModel

```
    public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public INavigationService NavigateToPage;
        public static List<string> names = new List<string>() { "Anzal", "Rashid", "Kamil", "Fahad" };
        public ObservableCollection<string> Mynames { get; set; }
        public MainPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationservice)
        {
            this.Title = "Run Time";
            NavigateToPage = navigationservice;
            for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; i++)
            {
                Mynames.Add(names[i]);

            }
            del = new DelegateCommand(
               () =>                                    
            NavigateToPage.Navigate(App.Expeirences.Second.ToString(),null);
               );
        }
    }
```

SecondPage.xaml

```
  <prism:SessionStateAwarePage
x:Class="Design3.Views.SecondPage"
xmlns:prism="using:Prism.Windows.Mvvm"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Design3"
prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding names}"/>
</Grid>
```

App.xaml.cs

```
      sealed partial class App : PrismUnityApplication
{
    public App()
    {  
      this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override Task OnInitializeAsync(IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        Container.RegisterInstance<INavigationService>(this.NavigationService);
        return base.OnInitializeAsync(args);
    }
    protected override Task OnLaunchApplicationAsync(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        this.NavigationService.Navigate(Expeirences.Main.ToString(), null);
        Window.Current.Activate();
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }
    public enum Expeirences
    {
        Main,
        Second
    }

}
```

Now the problem occurs..How can I bind my secondpage to mainpageviewmodel???How to use my ViewModelLocator??

Answer (score 0):

You want to register `MainpageViewModel` for `SecondPage` with the `ViewModelLocationProvider`, thus overriding the convention:

```
ViewModelLocationProvider.Register<SecondPage, MainpageViewModel>();
```

...preferably before navigating to the second page :-)

Comment: That doesn't work..Whether I need to resolve the container or something???

Comment: Do you get an exception? How do you know it doesn't work?

Comment: when navigated to the secondPage,it doesnot show the list box binded with names...While there is no exception or errors...

Comment: Add a breakpoint inside the view model locators resolve method and in the constructor of the view model. If it hits the first break point, look what goes wrong there (e.g. which type does it want to resolve)? If it hits the second, all should be well.

Comment: Actually I dont have viewmodellocator resolve method implemented..And also I have registered viemodel as you specified,in onlaunchapplicationasync method inside app.xaml.cs.. I am confused..Could you explain it clearly???

Comment: Why not in `OnInitializeAsync`? Can you try `Register( typeof(SecondPage).ToString() ...` (or `Register<SecondPage, MainpageViewModel>()`)?